# How to check for an element in a heterogenous list ( list of dictionaries, inner lists)

Tags: python, json, string, list

As a response to an api i am getting this output. Instead of a for loop with a k-v search, is there a way to do list.find("Image"), if present, i just need a boolean output. It can be present anywhere in the list but if it does exist, i just need a true / false.

```
    [{'relTo': {'id': '56qswWscQJK6-cnIoQSwmA', 'type': 'Image'}, 'attributes': {'imagerelstatus': {'values': [{'source': 'internal', 'locale': 'en-US', 'id': '6069da0c-ac0a-4912-af7a-2b06547a2c14', 'os': 'businessRule', 'osid': 'imagestatusvendorItementitytype_businessRule', 'ostype': 'businessRule', 'value': 'invalid'}]}}, 'id': '56qswWscQJK6-cnIoQSwmA'}, {'relTo': {'id': '3EZdi8lHRXWWko4SXSV0PA', 'type': 'Image'}, 'attributes': {'imagerelstatus': {'values': [{'source': 'internal', 'locale': 'en-US', 'id': 'ea25efd5-5825-480c-81de-b1e6e32dbdcb', 'os': 'businessRule', 'osid': 'imagestatusvendorItementitytype_businessRule', 'ostype': 'businessRule', 'value': 'invalid'}]}}, 'id': '3EZdi8lHRXWWko4SXSV0PA'}, {'relTo': {'id': 'Vm9wXWddTfCHhcWYg51Zdg', 'type': 'Image'}, 'attributes': {'imagerelstatus': {'values': [{'source': 'internal', 'locale': 'en-US', 'id': 'bbe78f14-e2a5-44e3-ae4f-dcdd4cc92d86', 'os': 'businessRule', 'osid': 'imagestatusvendorItementitytype_businessRule', 'ostype': 'businessRule', 'value': 'invalid'}]}}, 'id': 'Vm9wXWddTfCHhcWYg51Zdg'}, {'relTo': {'id': 'Gpr4J4XTSwmkPm7_cjwrTA', 'type': 'Image'}, 'attributes': {'imagerelstatus': {'values': [{'source': 'internal', 'locale': 'en-US', 'id': '7c272829-9e75-4a85-979d-20b8be0dbc2f', 'os': 'businessRule', 'osid': 'imagestatusvendorItementitytype_businessRule', 'ostype': 'businessRule', 'value': 'invalid'}]}}, 'id': 'Gpr4J4XTSwmkPm7_cjwrTA'}, {'relTo': {'id': 'P8-_RSF2QZOa_8Vfgzy-yQ', 'type': 'Image'}, 'attributes': {'imagerelstatus': {'values': [{'source': 'internal', 'locale': 'en-US', 'id': '6104653e-0f42-44b8-baca-a8d2334ba87b', 'os': 'businessRule', 'osid': 'imagestatusvendorItementitytype_businessRule', 'ostype': 'businessRule', 'value': 'invalid'}]}}, 'id': 'P8-_RSF2QZOa_8Vfgzy-yQ'}]
```

Comment: Case-sensitive word "Image" exists or not should be matched.

Comment: Are you looking for the *word* ``Image`` or the *string* ``Image``? What is the desired result for a response with ``... 'id' :'56qsGImageK6-cnIoQSwmA' ...`` but no occurrence of ``'Image'``?

Comment: only if it is present, i need the output, else it can be null, word Image works best

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let:

```
x = [{'relTo': {'id': '56qswWscQJK6-cnIoQSwmA', 'type': 'Image'}, 'attributes': {'imagerelstatus': {'values': [{'source': 'internal', 'locale': 'en-US', 'id': '6069da0c-ac0a-4912-af7a-2b06547a2c14', 'os': 'businessRule', 'osid': 'imagestatusvendorItementitytype_businessRule', 'ostype': 'businessRule', 'value': 'invalid'}]}}, 'id': '56qswWscQJK6-cnIoQSwmA'}, {'relTo': {'id': '3EZdi8lHRXWWko4SXSV0PA', 'type': 'Image'}, 'attributes': {'imagerelstatus': {'values': [{'source': 'internal', 'locale': 'en-US', 'id': 'ea25efd5-5825-480c-81de-b1e6e32dbdcb', 'os': 'businessRule', 'osid': 'imagestatusvendorItementitytype_businessRule', 'ostype': 'businessRule', 'value': 'invalid'}]}}, 'id': '3EZdi8lHRXWWko4SXSV0PA'}, {'relTo': {'id': 'Vm9wXWddTfCHhcWYg51Zdg', 'type': 'Image'}, 'attributes': {'imagerelstatus': {'values': [{'source': 'internal', 'locale': 'en-US', 'id': 'bbe78f14-e2a5-44e3-ae4f-dcdd4cc92d86', 'os': 'businessRule', 'osid': 'imagestatusvendorItementitytype_businessRule', 'ostype': 'businessRule', 'value': 'invalid'}]}}, 'id': 'Vm9wXWddTfCHhcWYg51Zdg'}, {'relTo': {'id': 'Gpr4J4XTSwmkPm7_cjwrTA', 'type': 'Image'}, 'attributes': {'imagerelstatus': {'values': [{'source': 'internal', 'locale': 'en-US', 'id': '7c272829-9e75-4a85-979d-20b8be0dbc2f', 'os': 'businessRule', 'osid': 'imagestatusvendorItementitytype_businessRule', 'ostype': 'businessRule', 'value': 'invalid'}]}}, 'id': 'Gpr4J4XTSwmkPm7_cjwrTA'}, {'relTo': {'id': 'P8-_RSF2QZOa_8Vfgzy-yQ', 'type': 'Image'}, 'attributes': {'imagerelstatus': {'values': [{'source': 'internal', 'locale': 'en-US', 'id': '6104653e-0f42-44b8-baca-a8d2334ba87b', 'os': 'businessRule', 'osid': 'imagestatusvendorItementitytype_businessRule', 'ostype': 'businessRule', 'value': 'invalid'}]}}, 'id': 'P8-_RSF2QZOa_8Vfgzy-yQ'}]
```

As you just need a bool:

```
any(i in str(x) for i in ['Image','image'])
```

or just:

```
"Image" in str(x)
```

or even better:

```
"'type': 'Image'" in str(x)
```

or should i say:

```
any(i in str(x) for i in ['"Image"',"'Image'"])
```

return is `Image` is present in the list.

Comment: is the search case-sensitive to Image and not image.?(match-case)

Comment: the original answer was correct as well, just wanted to match-case for "Image" only and i did not want for "image"

Comment: @Viv added both